# Did Sandahl Bergman lose a finger during the filming of Conan the Barbarian?

Tags: weapons, movies

> Further, the actress playing Valeria had her index finger severed during a fight scene where they inexplicably used a real sword instead of a prop, and then even more inexplicably gave it to an extra instead of a trained stuntman. The random dude parried the actresses' blow, the sword slipped, and off came her finger.

[Source](http://www.cracked.com/article_20853_5-amazing-performances-by-actors-who-werent-acting-part-3.html)

Is it true?

Did Sandahl Bergman lose her index finger? Was it reattached?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, she nearly lost her finger, but it was fixed. You can hear her describing the injury in this [youtube video](http://youtu.be/XCFF-Xp2qHs?t=20s) where she also shows the scar to a fan, who confirms that it is present.

> I almost lost my finger [...] The sword slid down and I was holding my sword and it cut this way through. [...] That's why my handwriting is hard, this is the writing finger.

She has all fingers though :-)

[image]